# Can't change text size in gedit

Tags: gedit, fonts

Within gedit I can go to the menu Edit > Preferences > Font & Colours, and change the font size here, but this seems to change the font size for the application itself, when I print something it still has small text.

How can I change the size of the text I'm writing, not the application labels and menus etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **gedit** the printing text size can be set from within the **File | Print** dialog.

Select the *Text Editor* tab and change the *Body* font size.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, I knew it would be a simple but for what ever reason I hadn't noticed that tab, cheers! :D