# Gedit won't let me change the text size: stuck in giant text mode

Tags: gedit, text-editor

At first glance this sounds like a duplicate of [Can't change text size in gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99821/cant-change-text-size-in-gedit), but it isn't: in that question they're actually talking about print size, I'm not.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Gedit 3.10.4.

Anyway - last week, to let one of my kids play with the text editor, I changed the default text size to be large, on the Edit/Preferences/"Font and Colour" tab.  Now, I can't change it back - I tick on the box to use the default "Ubuntu Monospace 13" font, and the box is ticked and then unticks itself straight away.  I can change the font size instead, and the change just reverts as soon as it's saved.

I think it might be due to some config file which has the wrong permissions:  if I open Gedit in sudo mode, I **can** change the font size.  But the change made here doesn't cross over back into "non-sudo" gedit.

The only config file I can find in home is `~/.config/gedit/accels` and the permissions are normal on that.  I think that's just a list of keyboard shortcuts anyway.  There's lots of other config files in `/usr/share/gedit/` but none of them show as being modified recently.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling gedit but it didn't make any difference.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: When you uninstall `gedit` it keeps the configuration unless you use the `--purge` flag.

Comment: ah, i'll try again....nope, didn't help.  I just noticed that it's all of the options that are locked, not just the font size.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds similar to this problem: [gedit "Manage External Tools" menu option doesn't appear](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045114/gedit-manage-external-tools-menu-option-doesnt-appear)

Use `namei` to find if sudo owns some of your configuration files:

```
$ namei -l ~/.config/gedit/tools
f: /home/rick/.config/gedit/tools
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwxr-xr-x rick rick rick
drwx------ rick rick .config
drwxr-xr-x root root gedit
drwxrwxr-x rick rick tools
```

If you see `root` appear as owner or group (**after** the first two directories, `/` and `home`) then use this command:

```
sudo chown -cR user:user /home/user
```

Where `user` is your user ID. ie `Max:Max /home/Max`

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have `~/.config/gedit/tools` - the only thing I have is `~/.config/gedit/accels` and the path down to that is all owned by max:max (my user/group).

Comment: chowning my whole home dir (as in that question) didn't help either, unfortunately.

Comment: I've uninstalled gedit and deleted everything I can find on my whole drive, that mentions gedit.  Then after installing it again I have the same problem...